# Certain elements of System setting missing after upgrading to ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-18.04

I upgraded to ubuntu 18.04 from 16.04 by using following commands :

`sudo apt update`
`sudo apt upgrade`
`sudo apt dist-upgrade`
`sudo apt-get autoremove`
`sudo apt install update-manager-core`
`sudo do-release-upgrade`

The upgrade was completed successfully but there were errors with some packages which I explicitly installed using **sudo apt install package-name**

currently lsb_release  -a gives:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

but the UI has not been updated and there are missing elements in system-settings like sound, notification, sharing etc.

also the wi-fi icon is missing but wi-fi is working.

I've tried 
'''
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center
'''
it's not helping
[ScreentShot of system settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVlya.png)